# Adding multiple cells in a column based on a value in another column but same rows

Tags: excel, vba

I apologize if this question has been answered before, I wasn't quite sure how to ask it. I'm making a postage report for work. There's an area that we enter in batch information Columns A-F(Batch #, Scheme, Drop Time, Total Pieces, Discount, and Postage). I've got an area in columns K-O to sum up the batches (All the pieces from batch 1 would total in column K)

Now sometimes we can have batch 1a, 1b, and up to 1c. What I am trying to do is sum up the total pieces of batch 1 even if there's more than one, all in one cell under the Total Pieces column. More specifically: Sum cells in Column D where the row has batch# in column A. Is there a formula to do this or should I revise the sheet differently?

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim iRow As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

With ws
.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
End With

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: What all have you tried?  Post your code.

Comment: @Rdster
Sorry for the late response :/

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim iRow As Long

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

With ws
    .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
    .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
    .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
    .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
    .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
    .Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
End With

Unload Me

End Sub

Comment: Edit your post with your code.

Comment: So I;m not sure what i was doing differently the other night (maybe i was too tired :P) but the sumif function is working as another commenter had suggested. I must have been typing it wrong. But trying it again, i think I'll just have to format the sheet a little differently for the totals section to be easier for mgmt to sift through. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `SUMIF()` to achieve this. You can find details or the use of this formula here: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php